# MPAndroidChart: yaxis is not aligned to zero It shows middle of the chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, yaxis

For set Y values I used this code snippet

```
ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    int sizeOfY = analyticsWeek.getGraph().size();
    if (sizeOfY > 7)
        sizeOfY = 7;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfY; i++) {
        Log.e("sizeOfY",analyticsWeek.getTitle()+":"+i);
        yVals.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("0"), i));
    }
```

It shows middle of graph with 0.0 values instead of show at aligned to xAxis when (0,1),(0,2) where (pointValue,Xaxis). As shown in image it comes in center of graph even if there is zero point values. It should be aligned to xAxis

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you set axis dependency?

```
dataSet.setAxisDependency(AxisDependency.RIGHT);
```

Comment: Not related to OP's question, but this line solved my issue when I wanted to show the RIGHT axis instead of the LEFT axis

Answer (score 1):

You should set the minimum value of your axis to `0` using `setAxisMinValue`, like this:

```
mChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(0);
mChart.getAxisRight().setAxisMinValue(0);
```

**Note:** Starting with version **`3.0.0`** of the library this has been renamed to `setAxisMinimum`:

```
mChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0);
mChart.getAxisRight().setAxisMinimum(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

chartObject.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(0.0f);

Works well for me!